# Where should I ask a question about Outlook desktop?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where do I ask a question about the Outlook desktop application that regards IT support?

Here is the question:

> Our company migrate from KerioConnect to Office 365 to better manage
> the emails. Lots of people in the company have the same problem, can't
> search for contacts when creating a new email and typing in the "To"
> field (Click on the "To" button correctly open the address book and
> the contacts are shown). I have 10 contacts in my personal folder,
> and with KerioConnect when I type the name of the person in the "To"
> field a list with contacts appear, after the migration this doesn't
> happened.  Typing the name in the box appear only the email that I have
> already write to, but not the email saved in contacts.
>
> This seems to be a problem only for some office installation. Here is
> a list:
>
> [image]
>
> Do you have any idea on how to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably best asked on the Microsoft user-to-user support forums, where Microsofties and MVPs regularly hang out, but if there is any Stack Exchange site that might be able to help you, it would be [Super User](https://superuser.com).

*ETA: Actually, since it's a company environment, it's more likely to be appropriate for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) than for Super User.*

Comment: Thanks for your help, I don't think super user is the right place: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You're correct; I missed the _company_ angle on this - generally, if it would be on-topic for Super User if dealing with it on an individual basis, it would likely be on-topic for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) in enterprise environments.